# Laravel 5.3 - flash data removed after redirect

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I am using Laravel 5.3

I have two models, `Parent` and `Student` with a many-to-many relationship between them and I want to add a `Parent` for a `Student` and vice versa.

My approach was:

1. Create a link from `Student` profile to add `Parent`, like so:

   `<a href="{{ route('students.parents.add', ['id' => $student->id]) }}" title="Add parent">Add Parent</a>`
2. Add the route `students.parents.add` with a controller method to flash the `id` to the session and redirect.

   ```
   // in web.php:
   Route::get('/students/{id}/parents/add', ['as' => 'students.parents.add', 'uses' => 'StudentController@addParent']);
   Route::resource('students', 'StudentController');

   // and in StudentsController:
   public function addParent($id)
   {
       return redirect()->route('parents.create')->with('associated_id', $id);
   }
   ```

   After that, clicking the button redirects to the `ParentsController` `create()` but the session data is not there when I try `return session()->all()`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not adding `web` middleware in your `routes.php` file as it is already added in the file `RouteServiceProvider.php` file.

If you now apply it again in your routes.php, you will see that web appears twice on the route list `php artisan route:list`. This exactly makes the flash data discard.

Comment: I came across this while googling the issue but it is not my case, since `route:list` shows the `web` middleware applied only once per route.